# PHP vs SSI in html forced environment

Tags: php, ssi

sorry for the strange title. I have a quite large website written in pure HTML. Now I have to make some standard areas of the site, single time editable. So I'm thinking about a smart way to include this elements through an external file.
I can't change the .html extension of the page and forcing the server to php-parse every page seems a waste of resources.

I must choose between:
1) including via SSI (I have read that it has bad performances)
2) mod_rewriting to fake .html extension and including via php include

What would you do? What's the fastest and least expensive way? Is one of them most SEO-friendly?

Comment: Are these files located in some easily mappable directory, so you can apply special parsing rules for them? There's another way, btw: iframes.

Comment: With SSI (Apache), all pages with the file types you specify are checked for SSI even if they do not have any. Also, read this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html#ssi

Comment: The "single time editable" concept you want has a name: DRY. It stands for `Don't Repeat Yourself` and I recommend learning more on it. Django (Framework) is very much in favour of this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is which of this technologies you know.

But with PHP you have a lot more possiblities.